# Can not comeback to "bimwork" mode when press Escape key on Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

If I'm in Bimwalk mode and press the Escape key, the viewer will switch to Orbit mode. So after that I can not go back to Bimwalk mode anymore except I reload the page again. I use the viewer as default and do not add any extension. How can i active bimwalk tool again ? Thank in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a non-customized version of Forge Viewer, you should see a "First Person" button in the toolbar that will always re-enable the BIM Walk mode. Is that not available for you?

[image]

As an alternative, you could enable the BIM Walk mode programatically (either from the devtools console or from a viewer extension if you decide to write one) using `viewer.toolController.activateTool('bimwalk')` or `NOP_VIEWER.toolController.activateTool('bimwalk')`.

Comment: The "Bimwalk" toolbar still visible for me all the time but when i click on it nothing happen. I figure out that this problem happen on **Viewer v7.6** when i change it back to **Viewer  v7.4** it work as expected. If i use the function `viewer.toolController.activateTool` It work fine for me but for the other tools like Orbit or Pan the active status of button when selected display not correct anymore. Thank for your answer. –